# I have this error in Tic tac Toe game Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read properties of undefined ( reading '0' )

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

This is my code
Can anyone tell me why I have
This error

> Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read properties of undefined ( reading '0' )

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const board = document.getElementById('board');
  const resetBtn = document.getElementById('resetBtn');
  const message = document.getElementById('message');

  let currentPlayer = 'X';

  let gameActive = true;

  let boardState = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];

  function makeMove(index) {
    if (boardState[index] === '' && gameActive) {
      boardState[index] = currentPlayer;

      renderBoard();

      checkWinner();

      currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';

      if (currentPlayer === 'O' && gameActive) {
        makeComputerMove();
      }
    }
  }

  function makeComputerMove() {
    let bestScore = -Infinity;

    let bestMove;

    console.log('boardState before making moves:', boardState);

    for (let i = 0; i < boardState.length; i++) {
      if (boardState[i] === '') {
        boardState[i] = 'O';

        console.log('boardState after making move:', boardState);

        let score = minimax(boardState.slice(), 0, false); // Pass a copy of the boardState array

        boardState[i] = '';

        if (score > bestScore) {
          bestScore = score;

          bestMove = i;
        }
      }
    }

    makeMove(bestMove);
  }

  function minimax(board, depth, isMaximizing) {
    console.log('minimax called with board:', board);

    let result = checkWinner(board);

    console.log('checkWinner result:', result);

    if (result !== null) {
      return scores[result];
    }

    if (isMaximizing) {
      let bestScore = -Infinity;

      for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i] === '') {
          board[i] = 'O';

          let score = minimax(board.slice(), depth + 1, false);

          board[i] = '';

          bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);
        }
      }

      console.log('maximizing bestScore:', bestScore);

      return bestScore;
    } else {
      let bestScore = Infinity;

      for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i] === '') {
          board[i] = 'X';

          let score = minimax(board.slice(), depth + 1, true);

          board[i] = '';

          bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
        }
      }

      console.log('minimizing bestScore:', bestScore);

      return bestScore;
    }
  }

  function checkWinner(board) {
    const winConditions = [
      [0, 1, 2],

      [3, 4, 5],

      [6, 7, 8],

      [0, 3, 6],

      [1, 4, 7],

      [2, 5, 8],

      [0, 4, 8],

      [2, 4, 6],
    ];

    for (let condition of winConditions) {
      const [a, b, c] = condition;

      if (board[a] !== '' && board[a] === board[b] && board[a] === board[c]) {
        gameActive = false;

        return board[a];
      }
    }

    if (!board.includes('')) {
      gameActive = false;

      return 'tie';
    }

    return null;
  }

  function renderBoard() {
    board.innerHTML = '';

    boardState.forEach((cell, index) => {
      const cellElement = document.createElement('div');

      cellElement.classList.add('cell');

      cellElement.innerText = cell;

      cellElement.addEventListener('click', () => makeMove(index));

      board.appendChild(cellElement);
    });
  }

  function resetBoard() {
    currentPlayer = 'X';

    gameActive = true;

    boardState = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];

    renderBoard();

    message.innerText = '';
  }

  resetBtn.addEventListener('click', resetBoard);

  const scores = {
    X: -10,

    O: 10,

    tie: 0,
  };

  renderBoard();
});
```

```css
#board{ 
  max-width: 6.5em;
}
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: thin solid blue;
  box-model: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">board</div>
<div id="message">message</div>
<button id="resetBtn" type="button">Start/Reset</button>
```

I want to make a Tic Tac Toe game playing with smart computer but I can't solve this error

> Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read properties of undefined ( reading '0' )

Please help and rewrite the correct code

Comment: which line of your double spaced code is the issue?

Comment: minimax is not a good match for Tic-Tac-Toe.  At the beginning, EVERY move will eventually lead to a win, so you're just going to pick the cells in order from the upper left.

Comment: Bug alert: `makeMove` calls `checkWinner` with no parameters. `checkWinner` throws with an error that parameter `board` is undefined. Rinse and repeat. I was unable to reproduce the error in the title.

Comment: Edited the code to create a stack snippet showing the error produced. Please feel free to roll back the edit or make changes to show the code that produces the error you encountered.

Comment: @traktor How is `"message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0` any useful?

Comment: @connexo I'm scratching my head for a suitable answer. Browsers have been known to lose track of where errors occur, but a combination of no filename, line 0, column 0 might be  a timer callback parameter supplied as text, or an error in an event handler set up in HTML. Do you have further context related to this post?

Answer (score 0):

The question in the title is not reproducible, so this answer focuses on fixing bugs in the code to get it working.

1. `checkWinner` has a parameter called `board`. This is a bit misleading as it takes a `boardState` array argument, not the `board` element in the DOM.

   - A quick solution is to change

     ```
      checkWinner();
     ```

     in `makeMove` to

     ```
      checkWinner(boardState);
     ```
2. While checking for the best computer move, `checkWinner` is called with potential `boardState` solutions that could result in player 'X' winning rather than the computer. When this happens `checkWinner` clears `activeGame` to indicate the game is over. Consequently when the the computer does find a move to make, it doesn't get rendered because the game is flagged as over.

   - A quick solution is to insert the statement

     ```
         activeGame = true;
     ```

     into `makeComputerMove` immediately before the existing call to `makeMove`.

Although these changes get the game working, the code is probably best treated as a learning exercise - the first computer choice of move takes a long time to calculate and seems to hang the browser before the user's first `X` can be rendered, and seems to take a lot of memory garbage collection for the browser to recover and continue. It is, however, interesting :-)